# How to get when run `top` command ports listed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to get when run `top` command ports listed ?
I get info about process but I need port to see ( process dies very quickly , 0 seconds,  and I cannot `grep` after `ps aux` ). Is possible to top command show port binded to proces ?

Comment: `lsof` might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see what processes are bound to which ports, use `netstat`:

```
sudo netstat -p
```

Flags:

```
p - Show the PID and process name of the application that owns each socket
```